# Parse.com query array

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I currently have this query for parse.com:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    PFQuery *activityQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activities"];


    [activityQuery whereKey:@"triathlete" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    [activityQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            _activityArray = objects;
            NSLog(@"activityArray = %@",_activityArray);

        }
    }];
```

And it stores all of the data from each each object in my database. My question is how can I get the data from the individual columns rather than everything in one array.

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain how you would like the data? With this query, you will get an array with all the activities the current user has performed. What would you prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can separate columns in different arrays, inside your block, like this:

```
[activityQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSMutableArray *column1 = [objects valueForKey:@"column1"];
            NSMutableArray *column2 = [objects valueForKey:@"column2"];
            NSMutableArray *column3 = [objects valueForKey:@"column3"];
        }
    }];
```

Then do whatever you need to do with each `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

to get the individual columns from the query result use the following manner

```
    [activityQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
(if!error){   
 for(PFObject *object in objects){
        // to print individual object one by one
    NSLog(@"%@",object);
    // to retrieve individual column  if the column is string type
    NSLog(@"%@",[object objectForkey:@"yourColumnName"]);

    }
}];
```